# Python input() funktion for html

Tags: python, html, ssh, pyscript

So i am pretty new to programming. I started with Python a week ago. A friend of mine and i rented an SSH server. I tried some small things i already knew about python. Such as the Input () Funktion. But if i try to use the input () funktion on the server there just pops up a Window with the IP of the server where i can fill in the value.

Is it possible to get insted of the pop up id window a input field with the explanaition what the user have to tippe in the field ?

I hope some body can help me and sry for my medium english.

Thats my html "code":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>DeXso's Project</title>

    
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

    
</head>
<body>
    <!--<input type="text" onclick="console.log('SUCK MY W')">-->
    

   
    <h1>Just a Test</h1>
    
    <py-script src="Test_input.py"></py-script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

And here is just the input() funktion of python:

```
number1 = input("Number1: ")
number2 = input("Number2: ")

print(number1 + number2)
```

---

Comment: https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/239

Comment: A note for the future - there is active work in PyScript in moving the runtime to a separate worker thread, in a way that allows for blocking function calls like this. Once that is implemented, it will be possible to have the input() method wait on, say, input in a textbox or in-window terminal. https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/pull/1333

Comment: There's no real reason to rent a ssh server if you are using pyscript. It runs in static websites served cheaply or for free from many locations. Because the compute is actually done inside the browser of the client machine. If you were running actual full typical Python or Python kernels on the remote machine then you'd have more real need for a server. Then if you were using typical "real" Python, the `input()` function would work. One easy approach would be to run Jupyter on the remote machine. If you are learning, it is probably easier to start with the traditional resources.